# EJS loop printing out extra entries

Tags: javascript, loops, each, ejs, logical-operators

I can't figure out why this EJS each loop is printing an **a href tel:** multiples times after trying a few different conceptual constraints.  I can not get this phone number to print once!

This loop statement is a sub loop to the parent loop for info.person which reads all the phone numbers listed.  The sub loop has to load as an each function (as far as my understanding), so I'm trying to limit it to only the first number.

Note: It's also very interesting because the SVG phone item only loads once.  But the a href is loading multiple times as part of the same IF statement!!!  I almost feel like this is a conflict between sneaky Google tracking and my use of Trisquel's Abrowser. (see: [Google Tracking](https://www.eff.org/deeplinks/2018/10/privacy-badger-now-fights-more-sneaky-google-tracking)).

This code prints one SVG for phones and multiple a href tel: items (see screenshot)

```
            <div class="row">
        <% if (info.phones){ %>
          <% var j = 0; %>
            <% $.each(info.phones, function(i, phone){ %>
                <% if (j == 0){ %>
                    <div class="col-xs-1"><img class="svg_icon" src="/images/svg/phone.svg"/></div><div class="col-xs-7"><a href='tel:<%= phone %>'><%= phone %></div>
                    <% j = 1; %>
                <% } %>
            <% }) %>
        <% } %>
        </div>
```

I had to use an image here because it is too difficult to paste code from the inspector but this is client side ejs.
[And here is what prints out successfully, and, just to clarify there is only one href=tel: in the whole page which here appears multiple times.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmXlE.png)

So I tried changing the sub loop iterator from i to j which makes sense because the parent loop uses i.  But the results.

```
            <div class="row">
        <% if (info.phones){ %>
            <% $.each(info.phones, function(j, phone){ %>
                <% if (j == 0){ %>
                    <div class="col-xs-1"><img class="svg_icon" src="/images/svg/phone.svg"/></div><div class="col-xs-7"><a href='tel:<%= phone %>'><%= phone %></div>
                <% } %>
            <% }) %>
        <% } %>
        </div>
```

[Behavior remains the same in the Brave browser.  Please notice one SVG for phone which is inside the IF statement.  And the phone number is printing again after the Email SVG!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtCjd.png)

Note #2: Note: this is for a project forked off from Datamade's MyRep project which very skillfully uses EJS to pull data from the Civic Info Project (free).

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I found the issue, and am a little embarrassed.
I had dinner and finally noticed the all important closing tag for

EJS was doing a good job of trying to find the closing tag without crashing which was beyond the boundary of the IF statement!

```
<a href='tel:<%= phone %>'><%= phone %>***</a>***</div>
```